# Async Pipe used to sort a list, is called each time there is a mouse or keyboard event - Angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular2-pipe

```
<div *ngFor="let student of mystudentsFiltered  | orderBy : ['-presence', 'unreadcount']>
```

In the above `for` template, I have used a pipe `orderBy`, which sorts the list, every time there is a status change of an item (student) in the list. Somehow, this pipe is being repeatedly called every time there is a mouse or keyboard event.

I researched more and found, **pipe** in Angular4 are **executed** every time there is a **change detection**. And Angular4 consider the following in the change detection mechanism as:

1) Events - click, submit, scroll,

2) XHR - Fetching data from a remote server

3) Timers - setTimeout(), setInterval()

How can I restrict the said pipe to be called on when there is a data change but not the default change detection events?

Comment: You have change the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` as `onPush` like this `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` though it is not recommended way to doing it as it leads to poor performance

Comment: @RahulSingh this is the first time I see somebody saying that `onPush` leads to poor performance. Using `onPush` properly can greatly **boost** the app performance, you just need to have a good understanding of Angular's change detection mechanism.

Comment: The performance is for using pipes for filtering . Pipes are not meant to be used as filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use order pipes or filter pipes. As you experienced yourself, this is bad for performance. You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe). You need to do the ordering in an service

Comment: I used the transform method in the pipe to be directly called from the service. Now with this, pipe is not being called on default change events (i.e. mouse events, etc)

Comment: That is probably because you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`